# Python MrJob Map Reduce: ValueError: too many values to unpack

Tags: python, mapreduce

I am processing a csv file in Map Reduce using MRjob library. 
This is the link for the CSV file: [Airplane Crashes and Fatalities Since 1908](https://opendata.socrata.com/Government/Airplane-Crashes-and-Fatalities-Since-1908/q2te-8cvq)

I am getting the following error when I run the script:

**ValueError: too many values to unpack.**

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob
from mrjob.step import MRStep

class planesCrashed(MRJob):
  def steps(self):
    return[
    MRStep(mapper=self.mapper_get_year,
           reducer=self.reducer_count_crash)
    ]
  def mapper_get_year(self,_,line):
    (Date,Time,Location,Operator,Flight,Route,Type,Registration,cnIn,Aboard,Fatalities,Ground,Summary) = line.split(',')
    yield Date,1

def reducer_count_crash(self,key,values):
    yield key,sum(values)

if __name__=='__main__':
     planesCrashed.run()
```

**EDIT:**
I found out what causes the error. The csv data file has many commas inside it, thus it needs to be escaped. 
So I want to know how the commas can be escaped.

Comment: First of all your class name should be PlanesCrashed. Second, your class name should not be PlanesCrashed too. The name is very very very bad here.

Comment: This is just for testing, not the final version. 
Do you know a solution to the error mentioned?

Comment: Any hope? I am facing the same problem.